# How to delete a content type field without deleting the whole view?

Tags: views, 8, entities

I was trying to delete a field from a content type . But it's deleting all the views which have that field in it.

I have some pages inside that view. I even checked in all the pages that this field is present , but not found.

**`Any idea to delete a field without deleting the whole view`** ??

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As per the following issue registered on Drupal.org, that is what  happening with D8 views hence you are observing that phenomenon. While in drupal 7 the view  gets automatically updated. You  can find the registered issue with drupal 8 core on  drupal.org at following link.

[When deleting a content type field, users do not realize the related View also is deleted](https://www.drupal.org/node/2468045)

That issue is in review phase, hence probably significant work would have been done on that issue. You need to refer that.

If you read the entire discussion there, currently they are working on the idea of [Comment #59.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2468045#comment-11713835) suggested by [@dawehner](https://www.drupal.org/u/dawehner) which is stated/pasted below,

> Here is alternative approach:
>
> - Don't delete existing views
> - Disable existing views and tell people which ones got disabled
> - Then the user can go back to this view, fix missing fields and call it a day

Comment: I had this same thing happen to me, but with Paragraphs. If you delete a Paragraph type which is being referenced by a paragraph field elsewhere, it will delete that field, regardless of if it holds other paragraph type references. There is work going on for that as well.

Comment: I have deleted the field from the view. And deleted the field , then also the view get deleted

Comment: @IcecreamJelly, It should not delete, just now I did check in my trial site it is not deleting. Just remove the field whichever you do not want from the view and save that view, then delete that field from the content type. AGAIN, IF THAT FIELD IT USED IN ANYWAY IN THE VIEW, THE VIEW WILL GET DELETED, THAT FIELD SHOULD NOT BE USED IN ANYWAY, like if you remove it from the content, but if it is gets used in the FILTER or Contextual filter then also it is not completely removed and although you removed it from the content still it is getting utilized in view someway, Then also it ill delete.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove references to the field in the Views before deleting the field.